# android dex library

Tags: android, compilation

I've an Android application which use a lot of librairies (in jar files). 
When I compile my application in dex file with the dex.bat tool, it's take a very long time because of the conversion of the jar libraries into dex format. 
So, my question is : how can I link librairies in dex format to my application instead of linking jar librairies ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know when it was solved, but now it is right here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject .
There is detailed article about Android libs: http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/android-application-android-libraries-and-jar-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

You're getting it in ADT21 [(Nov 13, 2012)](http://tools.android.com/download/adt-21-preview):
*Libraries (both jar files and library projects) are now pre-dexed, improving build time.*